# MS Flow stops working when I update the file in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel, flow

I have a MS Flow that updates a list in SharePoint from an Excel file that I manually upload.
Whenever I upload a new file, the MS Flow stops working, see, inside the Excel file I have a table, that I pull from another system, then the file is uploaded to a site inside SharePoint. Every time I upload a new file I have to update the MS Flow to grab the "new" file, the file is always named the same as the previous one.

This is the error that shows every time I update the file:

```
No table was found with the name '{235AC59A-72C7-4A62-B137-00E0B394AB3E}'.
clientRequestId: xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx
serviceRequestId: xxx-xx-xx-xxx-xxx
```

The table is named "Table 1" before the file is updated, after that, it is shown as below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to read a table from an Excel file that is periodically recreated**

You need to use the [Get Tables](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/excelonlinebusiness/#get-tables) action first. This lets you get all tables from your Excel file.

Then, you can select the first table and grab its unique 'id':
[image]

**Expression used to get unique table ID**

```
first(outputs('Get_tables')?['body/value'])['id']
```